# When an object returns false for `.valid?` , is there a way to find out why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

When an object returns false for `.valid?` , is there a way to find out why?

```
CardSignup.new(params[:card_signup]).valid?
=> false
```

Sounds great Rails..but why?

Sort of related, but here's an example. I'm doing this :

```
@card_signup.update_attributes("email"=>"asdfa@asfa.com")
=> false
```

But if I do this :

```
@card_signup.update_attribute("email", "asdfa@asfa.com")
=> true
```

Why would that work when I update the single attribute as opposed to `update_attributes`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should check the `@card_signup.errors` collection.

For your second question, the `update_attribute` method saves the record without validation procedure. On the opposite, `update_attributes` perform validations.

Comment: Thanks Jef! That answered quite a few questions all at once. Kind of like the update_attributes method.

Answer (score 1):

Single attribute updates don't go through the validation process.

If a constructed ActiveRecord object isn't valid, try accessing the `errors` method.

E.g.

```
c = CardSignup.new(params[:card_signup])
puts c.errors.to_a.inspect if !c.valid?
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a method `@card_signup.errors`.

Answer (score 0):

use `current_devise_model.errors` or `devise_model.find(id).errors`
current_devise_model -> example :user, :admin
this is will return `#<ActiveModel::Errors []>` with this you can resolve this issue mostly because of duplicated values updated or required attributes not updated